# How to get the indices of subarray in large array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays as follows:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
b = [3,5,8,10,11]
```

I want to find the index of subarray in main array if a number is present. The expected output is:

```
res = [2,4,7,9]
```

I have done as follows:

```
[3,5,8,10,11].each do |_element|
  res_array = []
  if [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].find_index(_element).present?
   res_array << (header_array.find_index(_element)
  end
  res_array
 end
```

But I think there is a better approach to do this.

Comment: Can `a` or `b` contain duplicates?

Comment: 1. Your next-to-last line (`res_array`) should follow what is now your last line (`end`); 2. `present?` is unnecessary, as `find_index` returns `nil` or a truthy value (an index); 3. one Ruby convention is for the name of a block variable to begin with an underscore (e.g., `_element` or, commonly, `_`) if the variable is not used in the block calculation, but  here `_element` Is used in the calculation.

Comment: Please answer @Stefan’s question. Could one have `a = [1,1]` and `b = [1,1]`? If so, should the return value be `[0,0]` or `[0,1]`? Please edit your question to state whether duplicates are permitted, and if they are, whether they are “used up” when there is a match. Moreover, when (as here) someone asks for clarification of a question, it is both rude and unprofessional to leave their comment unanswered.

Comment: What is "subarray"? What is "main array"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
b.map { |e| a.index(e) }.compact
#⇒ [2, 4, 7, 9]
```

or, more concise:

```
b.map(&a.method(:index)).compact
```

Comment: @Stefan’s solution is `O(N)`.

Comment: Yep. In hindsight, it was obvious :)

Answer (score 7):

If performance matters (i.e. if your arrays are *huge*), you can build a hash of all number-index pairs in `a`, using [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) and [`to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h):

```
a.each_with_index.to_h
#=> {1=>0, 2=>1, 3=>2, 4=>3, 5=>4, 6=>5, 7=>6, 8=>7, 9=>8, 10=>9}
```

A hash allows fetching the values (i.e. indices) for the numbers in `b` much faster (as opposed to traversing an array each time), e.g. via [`values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-values_at):

```
a.each_with_index.to_h.values_at(*b)
#=> [2, 4, 7, 9, nil]
```

Use [`compact`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-compact) to eliminate `nil` values:

```
a.each_with_index.to_h.values_at(*b).compact
#=> [2, 4, 7, 9]
```

or alternatively [`slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-slice) and [`values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-values):

```
a.each_with_index.to_h.slice(*b).values
#=> [2, 4, 7, 9]
```

Comment: This is definitely a way to go if performance is to be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simpler solution,

```
indxs = a.each_with_index.to_h
(a&b).map{|e| indxs[e]}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers so far traverse all of `a` once (@Stefan's) or traverse all or part of `a` `b.size` times. My answer traverses part or all of `a` once. It is relatively efficient when `a` is large, `b` is small relative to `a` and all elements in `b` appear in `a`.

My solution is particularly efficient when `a` is ordered in such a way that the elements of `b` typically appear towards the beginning of `a`. For example, `a` might be a list of last names sorted by decreasing frequency of occurrence in the general population (e.g., `['smith', 'jones',...]`) and `b` is a list of names to look up in `a`.

`a` and `b` may contain duplicates<sup>1</sup> and not all elements of `b` are guaranteed to be in `a`. I assume `b` is not empty.

**Code**

```
require 'set'

def lookup_index(a, b)
  b_set = b.to_set
  b_hash = {}
  a.each_with_index do |n,i|
    next unless b_set.include?(n)
    b_hash[n] = i
    b_set.delete(n)
    break if b_set.empty?
  end
  b_hash.values_at(*b)
end
```

I converted `b` to a set to make lookups comparable in speed to hash lookups (which should not be surprising considering that sets are implemented with an underlying hash). Hash lookups are very fast, of course.

**Examples**

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,8]
b = [3,5,8,10,11,5]
```

Note that in this example both `a` and `b` contain duplicates and `11` in `b` is not present in `a`.

```
lookup_index(a, b)
  #=> [2, 4, 7, 9, nil, 4]
```

Observe the array returned contains the index `4` twice, once for each `5` in `b`. Also, the array contains `nil` at index `4` to show that it is `b[4] #=> 11` that does not appear in `a`. Without the `nil` placeholder there would be no means to map the elements of `b` to indices in `a`. If, however, the `nil` placeholder is not desired, one may replace `b_hash.values_at(*b)` with `b_hash.values_at(*b).compact`, or, if duplicates are unwanted, with `b_hash.values_at(*b).compact.uniq`.

As a second example suppose we are given the following.

```
a = [*1..10_000]
b = 10.times.map { rand(100) }.shuffle
  #=> [30, 62, 36, 24, 41, 27, 83, 61, 15, 55]
lookup_index(a, b)
  #=> [29, 61, 35, 23, 40, 26, 82, 60, 14, 54]
```

Here the solution was found after the first `83` elements of `a` were enumerated.

<sup>1 My solution would be no more efficient if duplicates were not permitted in `a` and/or `b`.</sup>